# How to start H2 database command line without PG server and Web Console?

Tags: java, h2

I have the H2 database v1.4.199 on an AWS EC2 machine that I want to start in TCP mode via the command line, but it looks like by default the PG server and Web Console also start, which I don't want.

I'm using a very basic command to set the port. Here's the command and output:

```
$ java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcpPort 9092
TCP server running at tcp://10.1.64.202:9092 (only local connections)
PG server running at pg://10.1.64.202:5435 (only local connections)
Web Console server running at http://10.1.64.202:8082 (others can connect)
Failed to start a browser to open the URL http://10.1.64.202:8082: Browser detection failed, and java property 'h2.browser' and environment variable BROWSER are not set to a browser executable.
```

You can see the PG Server and Console Server are up, but I thought the PG Server and Web Console were something you had to *explicitly* enable? I also do *not* want outside connections to this H2 (my Java app is on the same EC2), so seeing that the console is configured so "others can connect" in the output is a bit concerning.

What's the right way to startup H2 to make this more restricted and safer?

edit: For more context a Java app on the localhost will connect with this code:

```
    String url = "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/" + filePath + ";MODE=MYSQL;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE";

    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
        .username("sa")
        .url(url)
        .driverClassName(org.h2.Driver.class.getName()).build();
```

The Java app connects just fine, but it shouldn't need the PG server and web console to make it work.

Comment: Careful that `-cp h2*.jar` will be expanded by the shell with space separating all jar files, when java requires `:` (`;` on Windows). It will work *only* when a single jar matches that pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server's help option may offer some guidance:

```
 java -cp h2.jar org.h2.tools.Server -?
```

The output includes this:

```
Starts the H2 Console (web-) server, TCP, and PG server.
Usage: java org.h2.tools.Server <options>
When running without options, -tcp, -web, -browser and -pg are started.
…
```

The solution is to start the TCP server explicitly:

```
java -cp h2.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -tcpPort 9092
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I read through the `-?` help but thought the `-tcp` was redundant since I specified `tcpPort 9092` and it the TCP server would start successfully. It's a bit confusing IMO, but I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I'm a long-time fan of [tag:h2], and I recall stumbling on this, too.